# Remove spacing before \chapter in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I am using the book style to write a research report and would like to know how to remove the top vertical space before a chapter heading. I need this for the 'Abstract' page. I would like it to start nearer to the top than standard chapters.

Comment: I don't know whether it would work, but have you tried \vspace{-5cm}?

Comment: Margin?  You mean vertical space?  Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801107/latex-positions-of-page-numbers-position-of-chapter-headings-chapters-and-tab?

Comment: @vivi \vspace didn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @charles The suggested thread seems relevant. Thanks.

Comment: I think the problem with \vspace is that the \chapter command comes after the \vspace and automatically starts at the top of a new page.  So \vspace's upward movement is of no help; \vspace's positioning is always done on the previous page.  You need another way, which can be using titlesec package.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An easy way is using the titlesec package. The appendix 9.2 of its documentation shows how the standard classes typeset their headings - it's not hard to copy and to modify those commands according to the own requirements.

Answer (score 27):

Here is some sample code using the titlesec package, Stefan's suggestion.  The titleformat command leaves everything at default values, but you need to include it (I think) for the titlespacing changes to work.  The second titlespacing command sets back to default values, with assumption that you wanted altered spacing only for first chapter:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}

% this alters "before" spacing (the second length argument) to 0
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
 % this changes "before" spacing back to its default of 50pt
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
First sentence of chapter.

\chapter{two}
First sentence of chapter.

\chapter{three}
First sentence of chapter.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Having the same issue, i tried out the titlesec solution, which somehow didn't work as expected (too many errors with Texshop 2.47 on OsX).

However, i worked out a simpler solution (at least for my case) with the geometry package. The deal is to call a new page geometry only for the page of interest and then restore the page geometry defined by fncychap.

```
% in the preamble
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}

% in the document
\frontmatter

% adapt geometry options to your needs
\newgeometry{textwidth=16cm,textheight=28cm,voffset=-2cm,bottom=0cm}
\chapter*{Abstract}
\markboth{}{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
% text
\restoregeometry
% from now on fncychap takes over again
\mainmatter
```